# Placement of adverbial and prepositional phrases in sentences

Tags: prepositions

Of the two sentences below, which would be correct?

> 1. I have sent a book at head office by bus
> 2. I have sent a book by bus at head office

The placement of "by bus" and "at head office" are different. I want to confirm which placement is correct in the above sentences.

Comment: Use “to the head office” and then either sentence works.

Answer (score 2):

Neither is correct, since you sent something **to** somewhere, not **at** somewhere.  *To* indicates direction.

Otherwise while there is a [recommended order to adverbs or adverbial phrases](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Order-of-Adverbs.htm), both are fine and natural English.  But if you want to follow the recommended order, it is:

> 1. Manner
> 2. Place
> 3. Frequency
> 4. Time
> 5. Purpose

So, in your example:

> I sent a book by bus (manner) to the head office (place).

Other examples:

> I have to run quickly (manner) down the street (place) each morning (frequency) after breakfast (time) in order to catch my bus to school (purpose).
>
> She buys dinner from the shop (place) every evening (frequency) for her children (purpose).

However, I think this "order" is as often broken as not. For example, when using verbs that imply *movement* it can be better to put the direction or location *first*, to avoid confusion:

> I sent a book to the head office (place) by bus (manner).

Or you just order it by what you think is important:

> She buys dinner for her children (purpose) every evening (frequency) from the shop (place).

Comment: It means we can use purpose,place and time either way? As above example shown

Comment: The recommended order is a good place to start, and a good rule to use if you're not sure.  But yes, most of the time, they can be in any order.

Comment: We can say that  the teacher is fighting against carroption in parliament. Or the teacher is fighting in parliament against carroption. Are either sentences correct?

Comment: Yes, either is fine -- but in this case there can be a slight emphasis to indicate which is more important -- either *what* the teacher is fighting against (corruption) or against *whom* she is fighting (parliament).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, "at head office" is incorrect.  When you say you sent a book at the head office, most English speakers assume you mean that you were at the office.  What you want here is "to" or "towards," so:

> 1. I have sent a book to the head office by bus
> 2. I have sent a book by bus to the head office.

To answer your question, these are both correct.